# python Django migrate issue

Tags: python, mysql, django

Here is the configuration of my setting.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'NAME': 'exercise',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306'
    }
}
```

when i run python manage.py migrate ,Django create two table in exercise database and i got a error like this:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: Incorrect datetime value: '2016-06-29 08:33:20.50
8803+00:00' for column 'applied' at row 1
```

Here is the two tables created by django:

```
+---------------------+
| Tables_in_exercise  |
+---------------------+
| django_content_type |
| django_migrations   |
+---------------------+
```

and when i insert the datetime into the table created by django like this:

```
mysql> insert into django_migrations(app,name,applied) values('aa','bb','2016-06
-29 08:33:20.508803+00:00');
```

it worked...

why mysql do not accept the value from django,but i can insert it ? how shoud i solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This Django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26113) suggests that MySQL Connector/Python 2.1.3 does not support Django 1.9.

You could either downgrade to Django 1.8, or switch to the `django.db.backends.mysql` backend with mysqlclient or MySQLdb (MySQLdb is Python 2 only).

Comment: You are right,thank you. have you ever meet this :auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length...Traceback (most recent

Comment: It's not a good idea to post tracebacks in the comments, they are unreadable. It sounds like a separate issue so you would be better to ask a new question.